# connection string to Postgres

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, app-config, npgsql

I am new to Postgres  and I need help with connection string.

My app using Entity Framework. I have this connectionString to MSSQL Server:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to my project i download a npgsql package (http://pgfoundry.org/projects/npgsql/) a need to help with editing connection string to Postgres database.

How to set providerName to npgsql?

Thank for help

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: I dont know how to set providerName to npgsql

Comment: I suggest you make this a part of the question. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["don't hard code your providers"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55890/Don-t-hard-code-your-DataProviders) discusses this in detail.

It shows a setting like what you want:

```
<add name="blah" providerName="Npgsql" 
  connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;
    User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"/>
```

but then explains *why you should not do this*, you should read the settings from your application's configuration file at runtime instead.